# How to negate specific regex if line starts with it?

Tags: python, regex

I have to get a text after `:note:` :

```
Command description

:note: Command note
another line of command note
:example: Command example
:example: Another command example

:argname arg: argument
:argdesc arg: argument description
:argreq arg: true
:argnote arg: Argument note
```

The result should be "Command note
another line of command note"

My original expression:
`re.findall(r":note: (.+)", self.help)`

I tried to use negative lookahead `(?!)` but I don't recognize how to use it in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the negative lookahead like this, matching the next line(s) that do not start with `:\w+:`

The group value will be returned by `re.findall`

```
:note: (.+(?:\r?\n(?!:[^:\r\n]+:).*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `:note:`  Match literally
- `(` **Group 1**

  - `.+` match 1+ chars except newlines
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n(?!:[^:\r\n]+:).*` Match a newline and use the negative lookahead to assert that the line does not start with `:` 1+ times any char except `:` or a newline and then match `:`
  - `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat to match all lines
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7plbxB/1)